# Optional binding in Swift not working in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, binding, option-type, cs193p

I am preparing for a segue to a TabViewController titles SmashTabController, which is hooked up to a TableViewController titled SmashTableView – if you haven't guessed by now, I'm following the Stanford 193P iOS course.

In my debug session I see that my destination VC IS the SmashTabController, but for some reason my optional binding always fails.

Any idea why this could be happening ?

Thank you so much in advance !

```
if let clicked = sender as? MentionsTableViewCell {
    if clicked.mentions != nil {
        let urlString = clicked.mentions!
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    } else if let stvc = destination as? SmashTabViewController {
        if let svc = stvc.presentedViewController as? SmashTableViewController {
            svc.newSearch = clicked.mentions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the `if let clicked` and step through the individual lines to find out which one is failing. Once you'll narrow this down to a single line, it will be easier to find what is wrong.

Comment: I've done that and it's the assignment to stvc. it's always failing, which I don't get

Answer (score 0):

```
if let clicked = sender as? MentionsTableViewCell {
        if clicked.mentions != nil {
            let urlString = clicked.mentions!
                if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
                }
            } else if let stvc = segue.destinationViewController as? SmashTabViewController {
            if let svc = stvc.presentedViewController as? SmashTableViewController {
                        svc.newSearch = clicked.mentions
                    }
        }
    }
```

I cant see where you actually give the destinationViewController in the prepareForSeque. I assume it is that TabBarController and then you want to pass the data to a view in that tabBar. This should work if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are doing there in the else-if part. My code usually looks like:

```
if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? TheDestinationViewController
```

or in case where the destination controller is wrapped in a navigation controller, it would be something like:

```
        if let nav = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
            if let targetController = nav.topViewController as? TheDestinationViewController {
                // pass on something?
            }
        }
```